# Function to create Foreign Server, does not create foreign server

Tags: postgresql, server, foreign-data-wrapper

I have created the function below to create a Foreign Server. The function runs **without error**, but nothing gets created. This is not a rights issue as I can run the individual commands just fine and the server gets created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sch.helper_create_linked_server(servername text, host text, port text, dbname text, localuser text, remoteuser text, password text, timeout text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare srv_name text;
tmp text;
begin

   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw; 
   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;

   execute format($s$ select srvname from pg_foreign_server where  srvname = %L $s$, servername) into srv_name; 

  if srv_name is null then
   execute format($ex$
        CREATE SERVER %1$I
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host %2$L, port %3$L, dbname %4$L, connect_timeout %5$L);          
        $ex$, servername, host, port, dbname, timeout, remoteuser);
    raise info 'server created: %', servername;

    execute format($ex$
        create user mapping for %I
        server %I
        options (user %L, password %L)
        $ex$, localuser, servername, remoteuser, password);
    raise info '%', 'umapping created';   

   perform format($$ ALTER SERVER %1$I OWNER TO %2$I $$, servername, remoteuser);
    raise info '%', 'assigned user to server';
   end if;

end $function$
```

I have printed out the command that gets generated and it is correct. This is how I call the function:

```
perform sch.helper_create_linked_server(link_name, conn_props->>'endpoint', conn_props->>'port', conn_props->>'db', conn_props->>'user', conn_props->>'user', rs_pwd, conn_props->>'timeout');
```

Also, all the `raise info` messages are printed as well, so the code is running. And no, the server is not already created.

I cannot see why this will not create.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you roll back the transaction.

Comment: well, i'm explicitly doing this in one.